# How do I get request.host in rails mailer preview?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, preview

Awesome: rails now offers a way to preview mailer views using a class that inherits from

```
 ActionMailer::Preview
```

Rails seems to be using this controller to set all this magic up:

```
Rails::MailersController#preview
```

Unfortunately, my app is multi-tenant, and my mailers rely on the request.host being passed to them so that they are styled according to the domain that they were triggered from.

I would love to be able to key off of the url in in the address bar when setting up may mailer previews. I'm having to do strange things to get this working (partly because I'm creating feature specs for these too), but mostly because I have to set up my mailers in a context that does not have access to the request object, even though my mailers need it to work properly.

```
class SiteMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def support_email_notification
    support_email = SupportEmail.first
    SiteMailer.support_email_notification(support_email, request).deliver
  end

  private

  def request
    request = Struct.new(:host).new
    request.host = 'local.myhost.net'
    request
  end
end
```

Currently the host is set statically so I can't really test the mailers against multiple hosts.

Answer (score -1):

`request` will not be available in models and mailers. The only way that can enable you to access `request` in a `model` or `mailer` is to pass the `request` from `controller`. Check the below example:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    book = Book.create(title: 'xyz', author: current_user)
    BookMailer.new_book_added(book.id, request).deliver
  end
end
```

and the mailer may look like below:

```
class BookMailer < ActionMailer::Base
     def new_book_added(book_id, request)
        @book = Book.find book_id
        @url  = books_url(@book, host: request.host_with_port )
        mail(:to => @book.author.email,
             :subject => "Your book is published")
     end
end
```

and since you mentioned your app is `multitenant` and assuming you're using `apartment` gem, You can use `Apartment::Tenant.current` which will give you the `subdomain`.

Comment: This answer would be the simple answer IF I had access to the controller. I'm not sure you fully understand the question. Please consult the documentation on mailer previews: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails The controller is built into rails, and the only thing I can think to do is perhaps override it somehow.

Answer (score -1):

In rails 5.2 you have ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes available, from the docs:

> Abstract super class that provides a thread-isolated attributes singleton, which resets automatically before and after each request. This allows you to keep all the per-request attributes easily available to the whole system.

I currently use it in my app to store request specific things that I need anywhere (even models, mailers, decorators etc. It has been super useful. Using ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes if set up correctly would allow to do things like:

```
Current.request
```

This is the set up that I have in my app:

In my models

```
#models/current.rb
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :request_id, :user_agent, :ip_address, :user, :request
end
```

Controllers concerns:

```
#controllers/set_current_request_details.rb
module SetCurrentRequestDetails
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action do
      Current.request_id = request.uuid
      Current.user_agent = request.user_agent
      Current.ip_address = request.ip
      Current.request = request
    end
  end
end
```

Controllers:

```
#controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SetCurrentRequestDetails

...
```

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html